# Iterate Through the Keys of an Object with a for...in Statement

Tags: javascript, object, dot, for-in-loop, square-bracket

Why is it that bracket notation allows the code to run meaning the count variable works, and when I use the dot notation the code doesn't work?[

> 

```js
const users = {
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
}

function countOnline(usersObj) {
  // Only change code below this line
  let count = 0;
  for (let user in usersObj){
    if (usersObj[user].online == true){
      count ++;
    }
  }
  return count;
  
  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naLzB.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop where you are using the dot notation, the "user" is not an index, it's a member of the usersObj array. Try just user.online instead, and it should work.